# Unsupported operant type(s) for -: ‘float’ and ‘str’

Tags: python

I have been working on a project and I thought I had an understanding of how to manipulate information in a dictionary into a float to use for comparison however I can see that that is not the case. Any suggestions?

```
country = "France"
url = 'https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/history?country='+country+'&status=confirmed'
print(url)
request = requests.get(url)
dct1 = json.loads(request.text)

key1 = "All"
key2 = "dates"
#datekey = specific date

confirmedcases = []
for datekey in dct1[key1][key2]:
    confirmedcases.append(float(dct1[key1][key2][datekey]))
    confirmedcases.append(datekey)
    
confirmedcases.reverse()
print(confirmedcases)


current_high = 0
new_cases = []
for i in range(1,len(confirmedcases)):
    new_cases.append(float(confirmedcases[i]) - (float(confirmedcases[i-1])))
    if confirmedcases[i] - confirmedcases[i-1] > current_high:
        current_high = confirmedcases[i] - confirmedcases[i-1]
        dct1 = dct1[i]
        
print(current_high)
input("press any key")
```

Comment: Suggestion: look at a traceback, which line produces the error, and think why. And if you are asking a question here, please include the whole traceback, so we also know which line produces the error

Comment: The problem is with the attribute in the dictionary precisely the date which cannot be converted into float. What does the last for loop do? Please give an explanation of the script. You can use `datetime` to play with dates

Answer (score 2):

The error raised is :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1043-c9ba12594a26> in <module>
     22 new_cases = []
     23 for i in range(1,len(confirmedcases)):
---> 24     new_cases.append(float(confirmedcases[i]) - (float(confirmedcases[i-1])))
     25     if confirmedcases[i] - confirmedcases[i-1] > current_high:
     26         current_high = confirmedcases[i] - confirmedcases[i-1]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020-01-22'
```

Indeed, `confirmedcases[i-1]` is `'2020-01-22'` that cannot be converted to float.

How did this happen? Let's look at `confirmedcases`:

```
['2020-01-22', 0.0, '2020-01-23', 0.0, '2020-01-24', 2.0, '2020-01-25', 3.0, ...]
```

This is likely not correct to have mixed the dates and values.

This happened in a previous block:

```
confirmedcases = []
for datekey in dct1[key1][key2]:
    confirmedcases.append(float(dct1[key1][key2][datekey]))
    confirmedcases.append(datekey) # why is the date added?
```

There are other issues in the code, but this gives you a good starting point to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

For Comparison, floats may not be that optimal, as it can get bit complicated to handle.

If possible, try to use Integers, if the dataset you receive contains the number of cases. (if any decimal values in them are not significant)

Else, can follow up on this solution to get an idea of how to go about comparisons with floats.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595453/8495683